# Pandas Lambda Function Format Month and Day

Tags: pandas, date, lambda

I have a DF "ltyc" that looks like this:

```
month  day  wind_speed
0      1    1   11.263604
1      1    2   11.971495
2      1    3   11.989080
3      1    4   12.558736
4      1    5   11.850899
```

And, i apply a lambda function:

```
ltyc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltyc["month"], format='%m').apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020))
```

To get it to look like this:

```
month  day  wind_speed       date
0      1    1   11.263604 2020-01-01
1      1    2   11.971495 2020-01-01
2      1    3   11.989080 2020-01-01
3      1    4   12.558736 2020-01-01
4      1    5   11.850899 2020-01-01
```

Except, I need it to look like this so that the days change also...but I cannot figure out how to format the lambda statement to do this instead as this is what I need.

```
month  day  wind_speed       date
0      1    1   11.263604 2020-01-01
1      1    2   11.971495 2020-01-02
2      1    3   11.989080 2020-01-03
3      1    4   12.558736 2020-01-04
4      1    5   11.850899 2020-01-05
```

I have tried this:

```
ltyc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltyc["month"], format='%m%d').apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020))
```

and i get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '1' does not match format '%m%d' (match)
```

Thank you for help since i'm trying to figure out the lambda functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a series with value `2020` and name `year`. Concat it to `['month', 'day']` and passing to `pd.to_datetime`. As long as, you passing a dataframe with columns names in this order `year, month, date`, pd.to_datetime will convert it to the appropriate datetime series.

@Allolz suggestion:

```
ltyc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltyc[['day', 'month']].assign(year=2020))

Out[367]:
   month  day  wind_speed       date
0      1    1   11.263604 2020-01-01
1      1    2   11.971495 2020-01-02
2      1    3   11.989080 2020-01-03
3      1    4   12.558736 2020-01-04
4      1    5   11.850899 2020-01-05
```

Or you may use `reindex` to create the sub-dataframe to pass to `pd.to_datetime`

```
ltyc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltyc.reindex(['year','month','day'], 
                                           axis=1, fill_value=2020))
```

---

**Original**:

```
s = pd.Series([2020]*len(ltyc), name='year')
ltyc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.concat([s, ltyc[['month','day']]], axis=1))
```

Comment: @ALollz: haha... you are right. I am so concern about the order of columns, so I made used of `pd.concat` :D

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to a previous answer, but does not persist the 'helper' column with the year.  In brief, we pass a data frame with three columns (year, month, day) to the `to_datetime()` function.

```
ltyc['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ltyc
                              .assign(year=2020)
                              .filter(['year', 'month', 'day'])
                             )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use your method and add `month` and `day` together with `.astype(str)` and then add `%d` to the format. The problem with your lambda is that you only considered month, so this is how you would consider month and day.

```
ltyc['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(ltyc["month"].astype(str) + '-' + ltyc["day"].astype(str),
                               format='%m-%d')
                .apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020)))
```

output:

```
    month   day wind_speed  date
0   1       1   11.263604   2020-01-01
1   1       2   11.971495   2020-01-02
2   1       3   11.989080   2020-01-03
3   1       4   12.558736   2020-01-04
4   1       5   11.850899   2020-01-05
```